# Sorting by Date Modified in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, sorting, date-modified

In prior versions of Windows I used to be able to sort my folders by date modified. If any files in those folders where added, removed, changed etc... the folder date would be updated. However, in Windows 8 this doesn't seem to be the case for me. Any suggestions?

---

Hm, this is very strange, I tried the following:

1. Created a parent folder called "TEST".
2. Created a child folder called "A" within it and a minute later created a second child folder called "B". Therefore "B" has a newer date modified date than "A" within our "TEST" folder.
3. Created a new file in "A". Therefore "A" should have a newer date modified date than "B", but it hasn't updated.

Please note that this is the case on my external hard drive, which is formatted to EXFAT. I tried exactly the same thing on my OS drive and it updates just fine. What could be the issue?

Comment: Nano, please register your account here. Then you can post comments on existing answers to your posts, or edit your question to add more info.

Comment: Do you have an external NTFS drive you can test with?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've just tested myself, and it works fine. I saved an image in a folder, and the modified date for the folder got updated.

Are you sure you are selecting the right columns to show? because regarding dates, you have 3 options, "date", "date created" and "date modified". the later is the one you want. Right click in the column headers and choose the ones you want.

Are you seeing those columns and still it doesn't show the modified date in the according column? If not, What date does it show instead ? the same as "date" alone? A screenshot would be useful.

Comment: This is very strange, I tried the following:
1. Created a parent folder called "TEST" with a child folder called "A" and then a 2nd child folder called "B". Therefore "B" has a newer date modified date than "A" within our "TEST" folder.
3. Created a new file in "A". Therefore "A" should have a newer date modified date than "B", but it hasn't updated.

Please note that this is the case on my external hard drive, which is formatted to EXFAT. I tried exactly the same thing on my OS drive and it updates just fine. What could be the issue? :S

Comment: well, as you mention, it may be the EXFAT file system. I don't know for sure, but it may be that. I also assume that your OS drive is NTFS, which is the most common this days. You could try to format your external drive to NTFS if you really need that feature, but better do more research of the topic (EXFAT and file dates) before proceeding. It may or may not worth the time depending on what you really need.

Comment: Yeah, it's really odd... but I tried the same tests on the same external drive formatted once in exfat and then in ntfs... exfat couldn't sort by date modified, but ntfs could... So ntfs it is for now.